# How to convert a number into a unknown number of a sets where each set consists of 3 numbers(0-255)?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to come up with a formula where the input is a number(**A**) and output is a set(**S**).

**S** consists of an unknown number of sets (**Sc**) where each **Sc** consists of 3 numbers(**n1**,**n2**,**n3**) where -1 < n < 256.

The formula should be able to answer

- the number of **Sc's** in **S**
- The 3 **n**'s in each **Sc**

**A** has a minimum value of 0 and the maximum value is unknown (not infinite). Would like for the formula to not rely on the possible max value of **A**

*I'll need this formula for a little side project where input is a phrase (any language) and the phrase is converted into a (color) gradient.*

Answer (score 1):

You will have to be more specific about your requirements if you want a useful answer. Here is a simple formula that outputs one set of 3 integers each in the range 0-255. But it may not be what you want.

Given an integer $A$, the three integers $(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ are calculated as follows:

$n_1 = A \mod 256$

$n_2 = \frac{A-n_1}{256} \mod 256$

$n_3 = \frac{A-n_1-256n_2}{256^2} \mod 256$

This will map $0$ to $(0,0,0)$, $1$ to $(1,0,0)$, $256$ to $(0,1,0)$, $257$ to $(1,1,0)$, $-1$ to $(255,255,255)$ etc.

But if the input value $A$ always lies in a small range (say between 0 and 1000) then the outputs vectors will all lie close together, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @Moo Ye, thank you for spotting that. I have fixed my answer.